# Split text by sentence but not by special patterns

Tags: r, regex, split

This is my sample text:

```
text = "First sentence. This is a second sentence. I like pets e.g. cats or birds."
```

I have a function which splits texts by sentence

```
library(stringi)
split_by_sentence <- function (text) {

  # split based on periods, exclams or question marks
  result <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\\.\\s|\\?|!") )

  result <- stri_trim_both(result)
  result <- result [nchar (result) > 0]

  if (length (result) == 0)
    result <- ""

  return (result)
}
```

which actually splits by punctuation characters. This is the output:

```
> split_by_sentence(text)
[1] "First sentence"            "This is a second sentence" "I like pets e.g"           "cats or birds."
```

Is there a possibility to exclude special patterns like "e.g."?

Comment: Thank you, but your solution deletes "e.g.". I would like to keep this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pattern, you can specify that you want to split at any punctuation mark that is followed by a space, if there is at least 2 alphanumeric characters prior to it (using lookaround). Which will result in:

```
unlist(strsplit(text, "(?<=[[:alnum:]]{3})[?!.]\\s", perl=TRUE))
#[1] "First sentence"                  "This is a second sentence"       "I like pets e.g. cats or birds."
```

If you want to keep the punctuation marks, then you can add the pattern inside the look-behind and only split on space:

```
unlist(strsplit(text, "(?<=[[:alnum:]]{3}[[?!.]])\\s", perl=TRUE))
# [1] "First sentence."                 "This is a second sentence."      "I like pets e.g. cats or birds."

text2 <- "I like pets (cats and birds) and horses. I have 1.8 bn. horses."

unlist(strsplit(text2, "(?<=[[:alnum:]]{3}[?!.])\\s", perl=TRUE))
#[1] "I like pets (cats and birds) and horses." "I have 1.8 bn. horses."
```

*N.B.: If you may have more than one space after the punctuation mark, you can put `\\s+` instead of `\\s` in the pattern*

Comment: @WinterMensch see the edit, it should work with your data now (except if you have shortcuts with 3 or more letters but then it could be word so...). Let me know if it's ok. (I also changed the marks so it's only dot, exclamation and question marks)

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(tokenizers)

text = "First sentence. This is a second sentence. I like pets e.g. cats or birds."
tokenize_sentences(text)
```

Output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "First sentence."                 "This is a second sentence."      "I like pets e.g. cats or birds."
```

Comment: Works nicely. But actually I have german texts and this function splits for example at "z.B." (which is the german equivalent to "e.g.") If this could be fixed, I´d be verry happy.

Comment: In that case regex solution suggested by @Cath is a better option as the inbuilt function like `Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator` in `openNLP` also fails for this example.